# Create new XDocument with XElement from StreamReader text

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to take an existing XML file and "embed" that into another node of another "Root" XML file. Suppose there's a path to an existing xml file...

```
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);

    string lines = reader.ReadLine();
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        lines = reader.ReadLine();
    }

    XDocument doc = new XDocument(
        new XComment("You can copy and paste or open the XML in Excel."),
        new XElement("Root",
            new XElement("logs",lines))
    );
```

I end up with things like this:

`<Root><logs>&lt;log&gt;&lt;username&gt;otonomy&lt;/`

Some decode encode help needed.

Comment: StreamReader is intended to read plain text; if the file contains XML, treat it as XML, not as text. See MarcinJuraszek's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `XElement.Load()` static method instead:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
        new XComment("You can copy and paste or open the XML in Excel."),
        new XElement("Root",
            new XElement("logs"
                XElement.Load(path)))
    );
```

It can take the `path` directly, so you don't have to deal with `StreamReader` at all.

Comment: I see why people say things like, "saweeet!" Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
string lines = File.ReadAllText( path );

XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XComment( "You can copy and paste or open the XML in Excel." ),
    new XElement( "Root",
        new XElement( "logs", XElement.Parse( lines ) ) ) );
```